# Google indexing iframe what dynamic created?

Tags: javascript, css

I site I dinamic created iframe :

```
document.createElement('iframe') ;
```

Is it whether the contents of the iframe will be indexed by a search engine?

If not, what can help?

Comment: What's your question? Is it whether the contents of the iframe will be indexed by a search engine?

Comment: @Alexander i see what you did there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "depends"

Google implements simple javascript evaluation on a page when it's parsing it so it will fetch data as if a user sees it but does not interact with it.

So if the user has to click on a button to see the iframe, it will not parse it.
If the iframe gets rendered on page load, it will see it.

Then is the matter of google indexes iframes. Yes it indexes the iframe, but no, it does not count the content of the iframe to your page. it will see it as a seperate page that gets its own ranking as if you were linking to it.